# django mysql foreign key constraint fails even though foreign key exists

Tags: mysql, django

The error I am getting :

(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`Tablename1`, CONSTRAINT `creative_id_refs_id_a7242fa2` FOREIGN KEY (`creative_id`) REFERENCES `Tablename2` (`id`))')

I can see that the 'id' exists in Tablename1 though !

Tablename2 has a "created_at" field that specifies when this entry was added. This insertion into Tablename1 happens 20 minutes after this created_at time !!

How is this even possible ?  This is so weird.

django version = 1.6.5 
mysql engine = InnoDB

Comment: I think you misunderstood the error message. The constraint exists between this two fields(creative_id --> id) so the fields must exist in the DB. You probably tried to save an object with foreign key to object that doesn't exists. Hence the constraint error is thrown.

Comment: Sorry if my post was a little ambiguous . I was trying to say the same thing as you . However there does exists a value/object  for the the field 'creative_id' in the other table ! 
Example query :
INSERT INTO `TableName2` (`creative_id`, `exchange_id`, `vast_tag`, `approval_status`, `reason`, `created_at`, `approved_at`, `adserver_id`) VALUES (1788125, 12, ‘randomstringexample', 0, NULL, '2016-03-09 18:48:02', '2016-03-09 18:48:02', 1); args=[1788125, 12, u'randomstringexample', 0, None, u'2016-03-09 18:48:02', u'2016-03-09 18:48:02', 1]

1788125 exists in the other table TableName1.

Comment: Do you run your insert inside the transaction? I saw similar problems inside a large transactions where one query tried to access object from transaction that was not yet committed.

Comment: I dont use transactions for the query .The django command that i use to save / the one thats throwing error is :

object_tablename1 = Tablename1(exchange_id=exchangeMap[entity], creative_id=key, vast_tag=vast)
object_tablename1.save()